# Graph with maximal number of faces

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to know if it is possible to prove that a triangle-free planar graph with N vertices, constructed only with straight lines of length one, and having the maximum possible number of faces, is only composed by quadrilaterals (as squares, for example).
It seems to be logic, but I didn't find a good argument...
Thanks in advance !

Comment: By "having the maximum possible number of faces", what constraint are you putting on the graph for a maximum to exist in the first place?

Comment: Ok, I forgot to say that we fix the number of vertices N.

Answer (score 2):

No.  With 5 vertices, a pentagon is optimal.  With 7 vertices, 2 faces are optimal.

After that, [A248333](http://oeis.org/A248333) is the maximal number of squares enclosed by N lattice points.

You're asking for a unit-distance planar graph.  It's unclear if you'd accept the graph of the cube, which has planar representations and unit-distance representations, but all the unit-distance embeddings have crossing edges.

You don't demand that the graph be polyhedral, so very likely the grid graphs are the optimal answers.

EDIT -- Also, all [even sided regular polygons can be divided into rhombuses](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ARegularPolygonWithAnEvenNumberOfSidesIsTheUnionOfRhombuses/).  With 46 vertices, you can get 36 faces out of an 18-gon. With a square grid, you can only get 33 faces.

[image]

Comment: Ok, but obviously I would like to have, maybe, points with degree 5, but only faces with 4 sides !

Comment: Ok, I think my question wasn't clear. If now we add the constraint that all angle is strictly greater than pi/3 (that is why I said "triangle-free"), I think that we have only points with degrees less than 5....